# SQLite to JSON in a simple JS function - parsing JSON

Tags: json, sqlite, parsing

I want to transform a SQLite Database into a JSON object. After searching the web I decided to write a function by myself. I'm still a beginner in JS/JSON/jQuery and I thought the following code should work:

```
function sqlite2json(){

    newJson = '{ "$resources": [';

    offlinedb = openDatabase (shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);

    offlinedb.transaction(function(transaction) {

        transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Zaehlliste;', [],
        function(transaction, result) {

            if (result != null && result.rows != null) {

                for (var k = 0; k < result.rows.length; k++) {

                    var row = result.rows.item(k);

                    newJson += '{ "Field0":"' + row.Field0 + '", "Field1":"' + row.Field1 + '", "Field2":"' + row.Field2 + '", "Field3":"' + row.Field3 + '", "Field4":"' + row.Field4 + '", "Field5":"' + row.Field5 + '"},'

                }

                jsonall = newJson + ']}';

                alert(jsonall); //shows me a correct JSON as string

                jsonobjoff = $.parseJSON(jsonall);

                for (i = 0; i < jsonobjoff.$resources.length; i++) {

                    $('#json').append("<li>" + jsonobjoff.$resources[i].Field0 + " " + jsonobjoff.$resources[i].Field1 + " " + jsonobjoff.$resources[i].Field2 + " " + jsonobjoff.$resources[i].Field3 + " " + jsonobjoff.$resources[i].Field4 + " " + jsonobjoff.$resources[i].Field5 + "</li>");  

                }

            }       

        },errorHandler);

    },errorHandler, nullHandler);   

}
```

This second for-loop and putting content into that element with its id="json" is just to control, that I finally got a true JSON object, but unfortunately there is no list appearing. The alert after declaring jsonall shows me a correct JSON-Object as a string. I think that parseJSON is not working, but I have no clue, why it is not working. Could it be that comma after the last entry of the JSON-Object? I know this is not clean, but it should still work...?

Comment: Paste your JSON into one of the several available online JSON verifiers to check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the json you generate is incorrect.
you add a trailing comma after every object (in your first for loop), but the last entry shouldn't add a comma, or it isnt valid json.

change this:

```
 newJson += '{ "Field0":"' + row.Field0 + '", "Field1":"' + row.Field1 + '", "Field2":"' + row.Field2 + '", "Field3":"' + row.Field3 + '", "Field4":"' + row.Field4 + '", "Field5":"' + row.Field5 + '"},';
```

to:

```
if(k > 0) newJson += ',';
 newJson += '{ "Field0":"' + row.Field0 + '", "Field1":"' + row.Field1 + '", "Field2":"' + row.Field2 + '", "Field3":"' + row.Field3 + '", "Field4":"' + row.Field4 + '", "Field5":"' + row.Field5 + '"}';
```

that will work (if you dont have special characters in your strings) 
i would recommend that you use this json encoder instead of manually generating the string, it will handle special characters too, which yours will have problems with: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

code for this:

change `newJson = '{ "$resources": [';` to `newJson = { $resources: [] };`

and in the loop:

```
newJson.$resources[k] = { Field0: row.Field0, Field1: row.Field1, Field2: row.Field2, Field3: row.Field3, Field4: row.Field4, Field5: row.Field5 };
```

you could just use `newJson.$resources[k] = row;` here, but if row has more Fields that you dont want to show, they will be taken too

create the json string:

```
jsonall = JSON.stringify(newJson);
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice!
I just changed my for-loop as you told me, this last comma disappeared, but it's still not working, so I guess there are special characters (it's german, so there will be several ä,ü,ö and ß). 
I just had a look at this encoder, but honestly I don't know how to use it correctly. I already copied this file to my project, but how can I now call this action? I hope you can give me a little advice :)

Comment: make sure you include the json2.js file, then just do `jsonall = JSON.stringify(result.rows);` before your alert. its that simple

Comment: I just did what you said and it gives back a JSON-Object displaying the number of entries 
    {"length":33}
A good sign is, that the parsed JSON gives back [object Object], showing that it works :) 
Now I just have to find out the correct term within the stringify-method... do you have an idea? :)

Comment: i added the code you need for that, i think its correct, but no guarantees, im doing this without testing after all

Comment: Thanks so much for your support, but unfortunately it's not working, there is no alert coming up now. Could it fail because of missing quotation marks? :S

Comment: i dont think i made a mistake, but cant be sure. look at this example http://jsfiddle.net/YegUe/ it very similar to what you are doing, you should be able to apply it to your code. also check the javascript console for errors, might just be a syntax error

Comment: I finally got it! I had $resources in quotation marks when declaring newJson.

Now everything works! :D Thank you so much, you definitely made my day! :)